# Non volatile switches

Tags: switches, non-volatile-memory

Sometimes, chemical reactions need a small push in the right path to start and then, the reaction sustains on its own. Now is it possible to make a non volatile microelectronic switch by using some phenomenon like this? Give a push in the right direction and the device conducts forever and if you pause the reaction long enough, the device stops conducting?

Comment: The Chemistry wording/example only causes confusion. An electrical switch makes and breaks a connection. Explain what you want using that: when X happens the switch closes, when Y happens the switch opens.

Comment: Well, I want to know what the x and y can be. Basically, I want a microelectronic switch that switches on or off permanently. You can't do this with regular transistors because they need an external power supply all the time. So I am in search of any possible way of making such a device.

Comment: *because they need an external power supply all the time* Lousy argument as **any** switch needs some form of power to switch on/off. It is still unclear what you want. X and Y can be anything from the color of your pants to the phase of the moon. If you don't know what conditions makes the switch change state then you're asking the unanswerable.

Comment: A latching relay does not need power to remember its state. See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relay#Latching_relay).

Comment: Steve G, this cannot be used in microelectronic circuits though, right?

Comment: Bimpelrekkie, I would like this hypothetical switch to conduct when given a pulse, and switch off when given another pulse. That is what I would love to see, but I don't see a way to do it

Comment: @PradyothShandilya are you trying to describe a flip flop?

Comment: Or simply a MOSFET? Depending on how you parse the question, the answer can be many different things. What exactly do you mean by "pulse"?

Comment: Not really. I just want a device to conduct or not conduct electricity without it needing an external source to maintain it in that state. You know how regular switches work, you press it, it switches on, and remains in that state without anyone holding it there. I just want a similar device, but way smaller, usable in computers and where the switching is done using pulses. A mosfet would require the gate potential to maintain that state.

Comment: The "mosfet requiring the gate potential to maintain that state" does not contradict any requirement that you have stated. Forever is a very long time. Nothing lasts forever. It follows that no switch can conduct forever. In that case, the answer is that no such device can possibly exist.

Comment: @SteveG *A latching relay does not need power to remember its state* Yes I know, there's one in my clock-thermostat. I was saying that there is no switch which does not need energy to **change** state.

Comment: Would be possible to use a triac for this I'd guess but it is very open to interpretation

Comment: You didn't provide any application to clarify what you are looking for, however this sounds a little like an SCR (aka thyristor) or Triac. You provide a trigger and the device turns on and stays on until the current through the device drops below a minimum threshold (near zero).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [floating-gate MOSFET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-gate_MOSFET) is the preferred way to implement a nonvolatile switch. There are literally billions of them in any given USB memory stick or SD card. They are also used in certain kinds of FPGAs directly as switches to route signals among the logic blocks.

There is no need for any esoteric chemical process.